# ARKit How to Pause video when out of tracking

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm playing with ARKit to put a video on tracked image.

The problem is that when I am not tracking the image, the video is still played and also the sound is played.

Is there any way to pause video when I'm not tracking the image?

```
func setupVideoOnNode(_ node: SCNNode, fromURL url: URL){


    var videoPlayerNode: SKVideoNode!      
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)

    videoPlayerNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
    videoPlayerNode.yScale = -1       

    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
    spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    videoPlayerNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width/2, y: spriteKitScene.size.height/2)
    videoPlayerNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoPlayerNode)

    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene

    videoPlayerNode.play()

}
```

How can I achieve it?

Thank you for your help.

I added the current code below.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

    let width = CGFloat(referenceImage.physicalSize.width)
    let height = CGFloat(referenceImage.physicalSize.height)


    let videoHolder = SCNNode()
    let videoHolderGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    videoHolder.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
    videoHolder.geometry = videoHolderGeometry


    if let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "img.scnassets/route", withExtension: "MOV"){
        setupVideoOnNode(videoHolder, fromURL: videoURL)
    }


    node.addChildNode(videoHolder)

    videoHolder.name = "route"
}


var videoPlayerNode: SKVideoNode?
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?


func setupVideoOnNode(_ node: SCNNode, fromURL url: URL){

    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)

    videoPlayerNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
    videoPlayerNode?.yScale = -1


    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
    spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    videoPlayerNode?.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width/2, y: spriteKitScene.size.height/2)
    videoPlayerNode?.size = spriteKitScene.size
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoPlayerNode!)


    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene


    videoPlayerNode?.play()
    videoPlayer.volume = 100

    videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none;
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.stateEnd),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name("AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"),
                                           object: videoPlayer.currentItem)

}


@objc func stateEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    let avPlayerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem
    avPlayerItem?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    if !sceneView.isNode(videoPlayerNode, insideFrustumOf: sceneView!.pointOfView) {
        videoPlayerNode?.pause()
    }
}
```

An error occurred with above code.

if !sceneView.isNode(videoPlayerNode, insideFrustumOf: sceneView!.pointOfView) {

Cannot convert value of type 'SKVideoNode?' to expected argument type 'SCNNode'

Comment: Hello, Do you get any solution for this? I also stuck there.

Comment: Hello, Not yet.
Have you tried the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

If you conform to `ARSessionDelegate`, you can use [`func session(ARSession, didUpdate: ARFrame)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session)
, along with [`isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode) to check if the video node is in frame, every frame, and pause if it is not.

```
var videoPlayerNode: SKVideoNode?      
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?

func setupVideoOnNode(_ node: SCNNode, fromURL url: URL){

    videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)

    videoPlayerNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
    videoPlayerNode?.yScale = -1       

    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))
    spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    videoPlayerNode?.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width/2, y: spriteKitScene.size.height/2)
    videoPlayerNode?.size = spriteKitScene.size
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoPlayerNode!)

    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene

    videoPlayerNode?.play()

}

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    if !sceneView.isNode(videoPlayerNode, insideFrustumOf: sceneView!.pointOfView) {
        videoPlayerNode?.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!

I'm trying to make the best of your advise, however I can't solve the problem in the next line.

if !sceneView.isNode(videoPlayerNode, insideFrustumOf: sceneView!.pointOfView) {

Cannot convert value of type 'SKVideoNode?' to expected argument type 'SCNNode'

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Pause the view's session
    sceneView.session.pause()
}
```